# my mysql query to return multiple totals based on multiple clauses throws up an exception

Tags: mysql, multi-level

I am trying to create a query which returns a total count of all listings with the typeID of 1 AND all listings with a typeID of 2 and all listings with a typeID of 3

I'm not sure im on the right lines but i have come up with this

```
SELECT a.Atotal, b.Btotal, c.Ctotal, u.userID, t.typeID 
FROM 
    (SELECT ul.userID, COUNT( ul.listingID ) AS Atotal
        FROM tbl_user_listing AS ul
        LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS t ON ul.listingID = t.listingID
        WHERE t.typeID =1
        GROUP BY ul.userID
    )AS a,
    (SELECT ul.userID, COUNT( ul.listingID ) AS Btotal
        FROM tbl_user_listing AS ul
        LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS t ON ul.listingID = t.listingID
        WHERE t.typeID =2
        GROUP BY ul.userID
    )AS b,
    (SELECT ul.userID, COUNT( ul.listingID ) AS Ctotal
        FROM tbl_user_listing AS ul
        LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS t ON ul.listingID = t.listingID
        WHERE t.typeID =3
        GROUP BY ul.userID
    )AS c,
FROM tbl_users AS u
WHERE u.userID =1
```

not surprisingly it is throwing up an exception on line 21

it says #1064 you have an error in your mysql syntax check manual blah de blah near 'FROM tbl_users AS u WHERE u.userID =1' AT LINE 21

can someone help me to understand where i am going wrong please and if this is the best method to achieve my desired result

many thanks

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "it is throwing up an exception" -> would be appreciated to know which one.

Comment: You're missing commas between the the subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: You have 2 FROM clauses

Comment: And you are using FROM twice

Comment: Should `Atotal` and `Ctotal` both use `t.typeID = 1`?

Comment: thanks for you input guys i have updated the question :) hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Please update your question with the table structure that you have for tbl_user_listing, tbl_listing_type, tbl_users and the desired output format. it'll help the community to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `JOIN` statements between the subqueries. Also, you can't have two `FROM` clauses. And you're missing the join conditions.

```
SELECT a.Atotal, b.Btotal, c.Ctotal, u.userID, t.typeID 
FROM users AS u
JOIN (SELECT ul.userID, COUNT( ul.listingID ) AS Atotal
        FROM tbl_user_listing AS ul
        LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS t ON ul.listingID = t.listingID
        WHERE t.typeID =1
        GROUP BY ul.userID
    )AS a ON u.userID = a.userID
JOIN (SELECT ul.userID, COUNT( ul.listingID ) AS Btotal
        FROM tbl_user_listing AS ul
        LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS t ON ul.listingID = t.listingID
        WHERE t.typeID =2
        GROUP BY ul.userID
    )AS b ON u.userID = b.userID
JOIN (SELECT ul.userID, COUNT( ul.listingID ) AS Ctotal
        FROM tbl_user_listing AS ul
        LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS t ON ul.listingID = t.listingID
        WHERE t.typeID =1
        GROUP BY ul.userID
    )AS c ON u.userID = c.userID
WHERE u.userID =1
```

However, it would be better to combine the subqueries into a single query:

```
SELECT SUM(t.typeID = 1) AS Atotal, SUM(t.typeID = 2) AS Btotal, SUM(t.typeID = 3) AS Ctotal,
        u.userID, t.typeID
FROM users AS u
JOIN tbl_user_listing AS ul ON ul.userID = u.userID
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS t ON ul.listingID = t.listingID
WHERE u.userID = 1
```

I'm guessing `t.typeID = 1` was a typo in your original `c` subquery.

Comment: wow thats brilliant, thank you so much!! yeah t.typeID = 1 in c sub query was a typo :)